# Что предпочтительнее: авторское тире или своё двоеточие? Может, точка - ещё лучше?

Tags: пунктуация

> Понятие красоты теперь будет тесно связано с соразмерностью и с точным
>   отражением её в ордерных формах. **Считается, что такой подход
>   позволяет направить мысль и подарить разгадку наблюдателю, пусть
>   исключительно на чувственном уровне – колонна несёт членения исходя из
>   тех же величин, что хранит в своём теле человек, а значит, человек –
>   мера всех вещей.** Через красоту, через соразмерность и гармонию
>   частей целого раскрывается древнейшее философское понятие эйдоса – как
>   некой подлинной составляющей каждой из вещей предметного мира, именно
>   так (согласно Платону) истинная идея становится легко распознаваемой.

А то два тире торчат рядышком.

Comment: Тут до тире ещё добраться нужно - постигнув, "из каких величин исходит колонна" при своём самосотворении, поглядывая на человека.

Comment: Хочешь - пропорций? Иди к доске, отвечай урок!

Comment: Что-то мне не удается найти ни красоты, ни гармонии в этих рассуждениях о красоте и гармонии.

Comment: Ну ребята, это ж почти черновик - первая корректура! Поможите христа ради.

Comment: Гм... Колонна несет и исходит, а человек хранит в своем теле...величины?

Comment: Злой М_Г, издатель выбрал именно этого автора, его (автора) представление о донесении информации до широких масс хочет лицезреть и опубликовать.

Comment: Ну не может колонна "нести исходя" или "исходить неся" - она же памятник!

Comment: Полёт мысли автора вдохновляет на маленькие шедевры:

Да, человек - он мера всех вещей,
Ведь в теле величины он хранит,
Из коих та колонна исходила, чей...
Членён в златых пропорциях гранит!

Comment: Автор ответил, что что-то тут термин, я не уточняла. Пока оставили: ***Считается, что такой подход позволяет направить мысль и подарить разгадку наблюдателю, пусть исключительно на чувственном уровне. Колонна несёт членения исходя из тех же пропорций, что хранит в своём теле человек, а значит, человек – мера всех вещей.***

Comment: Ну, то, что колонна делится на составные - "члены", - это-то известно?

Comment: "Несёт (что-то) исходя" значит "колонна исходит из своих соображений".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, двоеточие здесь вообще более уместно: 2 часть раскрывает содержание 1-й  -  какая именно разгадка?

А вот оборот "исходя из ..." я бы обособила:

Не обособляются бывшие деепричастия, которые утратили связь с глаголом и перешли в разряд служебных слов: начиная с (в значении «с такого-то времени»), исходя из (в значении «на основании»), смотря по (в значении «в соответствии»):

Однако в других контекстах обороты могут обособляться:
оборот со словами исходя из обособляется, если по смыслу соотносится с производителем действия, который может «исходить из чего-то»:

*Мы составили смету, исходя из ваших расчётов* (мы исходили из ваших расчётов).

А у нас ведь тоже есть деятель - колонна: *...колонна несёт членения, исходя из тех же величин,..* Здесь же не в значении "на основании", она не имеет членения, а именно несёт, как бы олицетворена, потому и исходит.

Answer (score 1):

> направить мысль и подарить разгадку наблюдателю

Напрaвить нож — заточить его, а направить мысль - сделать ее острее?

Варианты исправления:

(1) "направить мысль наблюдателя (указать куда) и подарить ему разгадку"
(2) мысль никуда не направлять, а просто "подарить разгадку наблюдателю".
(3) "подсказать", а не "подарить".

> подарить разгадку наблюдателю, пусть исключительно на чувственном уровне – ...

Вариант исправления:

"подсказать наблюдателю разгадку, пусть исключительно на чувственном уровне: (разгадка)"

> а значит, человек – мера всех вещей

Как я понимаю, ищем разгадку красоты. Она состоит в том, что пропорции колонны подобны пропорциям человеческого тела. А то, что человек есть мера всех вещей, — не вывод, а исходная точка в поисках разгадки.

> понятие эйдоса – как некой подлинной составляющей

Вариант исправления:

"понятие эйдоса как некой подлинной составляющей"